# Calculate Area under the curve in Histogram using Android Opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am doing an android project in which I have two dots in a picture and I need to calculate average b/w both dots. One is small and slightly transparent, other one is dark and big circle (dot). So I want to calculate average b/w them or difference b/w them. Dots colors are in red. I am doing this in matlab by making histogram and select both histogram. Matlab give me area under the curve then I easily calculate difference or average b/w two images. I made histogram but not able to get average b/w two dots. My Opencv histogram code is

```
Mat rgba = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, rgba);

                // Get the bitmap size.
                Size rgbaSize = rgba.size();
                // Set the amount of bars in the histogram.
                int histSize = 256;
                MatOfInt histogramSize = new MatOfInt(histSize);

                // Set the height of the histogram and width of the bar.
                int histogramHeight = (int) rgbaSize.height;
                int binWidth = 5;

                // Set the value range.
                MatOfFloat histogramRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);

                // Create two separate lists: one for colors and one for channels (these will be used as separate datasets).
                Scalar[] colorsRgb = new Scalar[]{new Scalar(220, 0, 0, 255), new Scalar(0, 200, 0, 255), new Scalar(0, 0, 200, 255)};
                MatOfInt[] channels = new MatOfInt[]{new MatOfInt(0), new MatOfInt(1), new MatOfInt(2)};

                // Create an array to be saved in the histogram and a second array, on which the histogram chart will be drawn.
                Mat[] histograms = new Mat[]{new Mat(), new Mat(), new Mat()};
                Mat histMatBitmap = new Mat(rgbaSize, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(256, 256, 256));
               // Mat histMatBitmap = new Mat(rgbaSize, rgba.type());

                for ( int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++ ) {
                    Imgproc.calcHist(Collections.singletonList(rgba), channels[0], new Mat(), histograms[i], histogramSize, histogramRange);
                    Core.normalize(histograms[i], histograms[i], histogramHeight, 0, Core.NORM_INF);
                    for ( int j = 0; j < histSize; j++ ) {
                        Point p1 = new Point(binWidth * (j - 1), histogramHeight - Math.round(histograms[i].get(j - 1, 0)[0]));
                        Point p2 = new Point(binWidth * j, histogramHeight - Math.round(histograms[i].get(j, 0)[0]));
                        Imgproc.line(histMatBitmap, p1, p2, colorsRgb[0], 3, 8, 0);
                    }
                }


                //convert Mat to bitmap
                Bitmap graphBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(histMatBitmap.cols(), histMatBitmap.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Utils.matToBitmap(histMatBitmap, graphBitmap);

                // show histogram
                histogramImageView.setImageBitmap(graphBitmap)
```

Original code [Link](https://blog.zaven.co/opencv-advanced-android-development-drawing-histogram/)

My Image is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUR8F.jpg)

and result image is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsr8A.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and sample images. Also, maybe add images, results, etc. from your successful Matlab examples to further illustrate, what you _exactly_ want to achieve.

Comment: Please check I Uploaded

Comment: Not sure I really understand the problem---the area of a histogram is just the sum of the histogram boxes; the heights are given by the quantity and the width given by the width of the bins. You can just calculate it with a simple for loop, looping through each bin in the histogram.